# Recuadro en panel de Stack Overflow Meta en español se muestra en inglés y no se encuentra en transifex

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, traducciones

Al acceder a Meta en modo incógnito y sin iniciar sesión se muestra un recuadro en panel derecho con la mayor parte de su contenido en inglés:

[image: Recuadro bienvenida Meta]

> Welcome!
>
> This site is for discussion about Stack Overflow en español. You must have an account there to participate.
>   ayuda »

Mariano y yo, al menos, buscamos `Welcome!` en Transifex pero no lo encontramos.

Favor de agregarlo.

Comment: Y reción busqué `This site is for discussion about` y nada, bueno nada idéntico, poniendo comillas nada de nada.

Comment: Mismo caso para PT, pero RU y JA lo tienen traducido.... hmmmm

Comment: Busquen “This site is for **discussion**” (con **, no estoy en la computadora).

Comment: @g3rv4 : Hecho (`This site is for **discussion**`) --> No results found.

Comment: Al buscar "This site is for" devuelve sólo una cadena --> "Warning: this site is for Stack Exchange developers and staff - it is used for development and testing."

Comment: Lo encontré... está en un SiteSetting que Juan va a tener que modificar. Por cómo funciona el código que lo genera, no es posible agregarlo a Transifex.

Comment: Reetiquetemos entonces para mantenerle la lista limpia a g3rv4

Comment: Listo! aprovechando mis nuevos poderes de dev moderador

Comment: @g3rv4 y otro caso más en que sale en inglés. Ahora en la sección [medallas](/help/badges): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCFfT.png

Comment: @fedorqui este es el conocido caso de... el bug de las traducciones fantasmas que se van y vuelven

Comment: @g3rv4 empieza a ser preocupante. ¿Están al corriente los desarroladores de core?

Comment: @fedorqui comparto la preocupación. La persona que lo va a arreglar está al tanto y me confirmó que va a trabajar en eso en breves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listo ya, habíamos encontrado problemas con cambiar esto por cuestión de permisos pero al [añadir a g3rv4 al grupo de moderadores](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3111/tenemos-an-un-moderador-adicional) (aunque no actúe como moderador oficial), hemos podido hacerle un avance a este tipo de cosas.