# Tenemos un nuevo moderador: g3rv4

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Tenemos el gran privilegio de tener a [g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) como miembro de la comunidad y también como [empleado de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team).  Él nos ha estado ayudando con el sitio y últimamente con las traducciones. A pesar de que sea empleado, existen restricciones que no puede superar actualmente a menos que sea moderador (un usuario con diamante).

Los que han tenido la buena experiencia de interactuar con [g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) pueden ser testigos de lo hábil y amable que es.  Cualquier empleado de Stack Overflow puede unirse a cualquier sitio de [nuestra red](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) y automáticamente ser usuario con diamante. Pero él no quiso hacerlo por miedo de que la comunidad lo tratara diferente.

Resulta que al meternos al código del sitio existen límites que solamente un empleado/moderador puede superar.  Por eso, le he invitado a [g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) a que se convierta en moderador.

¿Qué significa esto? Bueno, él no va a tomar parte en las decisiones del sitio como [nuestro equipo de moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) lo hace. Él no va a participar en las decisiones que tenga ese grupo tampoco.  Solamente se une con nosotros como moderador para ayudar a la comunidad a resolver problemas que requieren a un empleado dev con poderes de moderador.

Así que me gustaría presentarles a nuestro nuevo ...ahem....moderador: [g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4).

[image: g3rv4]

¡Por favor ayúdenme a darle la bienvenida! Y cualquier pregunta que tengan, aquí estamos para responderla.

Comment: ¿Soy el único al que esta información le parece confusa?

Comment: Yo creo que si eres el unico.

Answer (score 24):

**Actualización:** A partir del 2 de abril de 2019 no soy más moderador de SOes :) pedí esto para poder participar como un usuario más, votando, haciendo reportes y opinando sin el diamante en el medio. Hace varios meses que no uso el diamante.

---

Gracias Juan!

Para dar un poco de detalles de por qué esto es necesario: en el código de Q&A, el objeto `User` tiene una propiedad `IsDeveloper` que chequea dos cosas:

1. El usuario es mod
2. El tipo de usuario en la base de datos es `Developer`

La razón para que esté el punto 1 ahí, es que este chequeo se hace en muchos muchos muchos lugares... y no queremos, para cada una de estas veces, estar chequeando el tipo de usuario (porque si bien suena a que es un campo, esto no es tan así... está en una base distinta, porque uno es Developer en todos los sitios de la red, pero no mod en todos los sitios de la red).

Entonces... el punto 1 evita el chequeo para toooodos los usuarios que no son mod (99.999% de los casos), teniendo un impacto en la performance significativo.

El objetivo de esto es sólo (con acento) tener una herramienta más para poder resolver los temitas con las traducciones de forma más eficiente. De ninguna forma mis opiniones deberían ser tomadas con el mismo peso que las de Juan o las de los moderadores elegidos. Yo soy sólo moderador por una razón práctica.

Comment: Bienvenido! (si es que aplica). Ya era hora de que te sacaras el bozal :-) Es un paso más que obvio. Te queda bien el diamante.

Comment: ¡Yo tamibién! (te doy la bienvenida) y ¡Gracias! (por la disposición y apoyo que das más allá de tus obligaciones como "employee")

Comment: ¡Felicitaciones! Un honor que el gran @g3rv4 tenga su diamante. Entiendo que a primera impresión te han vestido con el diamante por el tema de las traducciones, aunque espero que una vez que se haya solucionado esto de igual forma sigas como parte del equipo :D ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: Por fin hombre.. Bienvenido!!!!!!

Comment: Es una muy buena noticia. Algo totalmente lógico y necesario en estos momentos. Gracias por la ayuda que prestas desinteresadamente :)

Comment: gracias amiguitos! la verdad es que personalmente estaba un poco preocupado porque quedaran claros los motivos. Me alegran mucho los comentarios <3

Comment: eeeeepaaaa!!! Felicitaciones hermano :D gracias por colaborar con el crecimiento de toda la hermandad de SOes

Comment: Es genial que seas moderador, estoy seguro que vas a moderar bien y complementar con los que ya están.

Answer (score -1):

Si g3rv4 se hubiese presentado a las elecciones es posible que le hubiese votado.

Si hubiese nuevas elecciones y g3rv4 se presentase es posible que le votase.

Aunque me parece que los empleados no se puden presentar. No lo he leído en ningún sitio, pero esa impresión me da por lo visto hasta ahora.

Pero lo que se ha hecho es confuso. Es moderador (tiene diamante) pero no es moderador ([no aparece aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)). Hará algunas cosas que los moderadores no pueden hacer y no hará otras cosas que los moderadores sí pueden hacer. Yo elegiría otra palabra distinta de moderador.

Pero todo lo anterior es solo una cuestión de nomenclatura. A nivel operativo esta es una excelente noticia. Bienvenido g3rv4.

Propongo que le llamemos superdesarrollador. Es una unión de superusuario (root) y desarrollador que creo refleja mejor lo que hace. Un desarrollador no tiene porque tener acceso a toda la máquina, o en este caso al sitio. El superusuario sí lo tiene pero no tiene por qué programar. Y el superdesarrollador hace ambas cosas.

Comment: Quizás ayude a que no sea tan confuso ver otro caso similar: JuanM tiene el diamante (es empleado de SO, con acceso de moderador de SOes), y tampoco aparece listado como usuario moderador del sitio... No sé qué término te conviene aplicarle, pero usando SOX podés diferenciarlo viéndole el logo de SO junto a su nombre ;-)

Comment: @Mariano ¡Exacto! A JuanM no se le llama Moderador sino Gestor de Comunidad. Lo razonable sería algo similar con g3rv4.

Comment: ¿Qué tal llamarlo simplemente g3rv4? :-)

Comment: @Mariano ¡Gran idea! El título sería "Tenemos un nuevo g3rv4: g3rv4" ;-)

Comment: un par de comentarios: 0) Gracias por los potenciales votos! 1) Los empleados nos podemos presentar a elecciones 2) diamante sin aparecer en la lista de mods es la situación de todos los devs que necesitan diamante por alguna razón (por ejemplo [Samo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7/m0sa?tab=profile)). No somos "moderadores" con todas las de la ley porque si dejamos de trabajar en SO, se nos va el diamante (cosa que no pasa con los moderadores reales)