# ¿Un desarrollador moderador debería aparecer en el Listado de Moderadores?

Tags: discusión, moderadores, usuarios

Recientemente se nombró a @g3rv4 moderador del sitio: [Tenemos un nuevo moderador: g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3111/tenemos-un-nuevo-moderador-g3rv4), lo que me parece genial. Sin embargo estaba revisando la lista de moderadores y él no aparece en esta lista.

**¿A qué se debe esto?**

**¿Es normal o es un bug?**

A continuación una captura de lo que menciono:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es normal y está bien que así sea.

g3rv4 entró como moderador, teniendo los mismos permisos y accesos que nuestros 3 moderadores electos (sumado a sus otros permisos por ser un desarrollador, empleado de SO). Sin embargo, no entró en la misma calidad que un moderador electo.

Su tarea no es la misma: no está para limpiar reportes y revisar preguntas y respuestas, por lo que está bien que no aparezca dentro de esa página... -Vamos, ¡ya lo molestamos lo suficiente como para que encima aparezca de forma tan pública! :-)

Recordemos que cualquier desarrollador puede configurarse como moderador de cualquiera de los sitios de SE. Desde mi punto de vista, el anuncio de Juan fue más bien una formalidad (que está genial que hayan procedido así), cuidando la interacción con el resto de la comunidad, e informando los cambios.

Veamos un ejemplo en SO: [m0sa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa) es otro desarrollador, y moderador en SO, pero no aparece en el [listado de moderadores](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Quizás te interese leer esta publicación de Tim Post, respondiendo a si se debería identificar de forma diferente al staff, y de la continua dicotomía de tener el diamante: [Split visualization of employee and moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341671/5290909).

Comment: Entonces solo los moderadores ganadores por elección de comunidad aparecen ahi, pensaba que todos los usuarios diamantados aparecían ahi, anteriormente luigi o arteze aparecian ahí, de ahi nace la duda, y claro me parece bien, ya hace un trabajo enorme @g3rva, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @JuanPinzón si bien no sé si se configura automático o no (aunque sospecho que manualmente), Konamiman, Luiggi, Miquel, ArtEze y fredyfx fueron moderadores electos (por el CM) durante el beta, y en la misma calidad que los moderadores actuales (electos por la comunidad).

Comment: Y agrego otro ejemplo más claro: JuanM también tiene el diamante (es empleado de SO, con acceso de moderador de SOes), y tampoco aparece como moderador del sitio.

Comment: @Mariano el ejemplo de Samo es el más claro... [m0sa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7/m0sa?tab=profile) también es moderador en SOes :)