# Gracias por tanto, g3rv4

Tags: discusión, usuarios

Como no entro en el chat, no me había enterado: [g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) ya no trabaja en Stack Overflow. <sub>Bueno, de hecho ahora caigo en que me lo dijo Pikoh hace unos días, pero no lo había interiorizado hasta que de repente todo es más complicado.</sub>

A lo largo de los años, g3rv4 ha ido regalando a la comunidad muchas de sus horas libres en desarrollar soluciones para hacer que esto funcione mejor. Es decir, era empleado de Stack Overflow y contactaba con otros desarrolladores para entender mejor la infraestructura, conocimientos que luego utilizaba en su tiempo libre (¡insisto!) para buscar mejores maneras de hacer las cosas.

- Así de memoria pienso en su capacidad para entender Transifex, ver que era un poco complicado de gestionar y crear https://traducir.win para gestionar las traducciones de un modo mucho más ágil. También ayudó que explicara en [¿Por qué aparece <X> en inglés? ¿Estamos perdiendo traducciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4468/83) y  [Traduciendo el sitio... Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/83).
- El Centro de ayuda está cambiando constantemente y puso en marcha un [sistema vía GitHub para sugerir mejoras en las traducciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/83) con el que mejoramos muchísimo los artículos a lo largo del tiempo.
- También, puso en marchas las [advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83) con las que los usuarios hacen mejores preguntas.

Y ahora te tuteo y hablo directamente a ti, g3rv4 :)

Sin duda, tus contribuciones técnicas han hecho de este un sitio mucho mejor. Apenas he interactuado contigo, pero siempre has tenido un trato exquisito que seguro que debe ser extensivo al chat.

Por ello, quería darte las gracias por tanto, g3rv4. Mucho éxito y ojalá que algún CM tome el relevo en todas estas iniciativas.

¡Un abrazo grande!

Comment: Yo sabia que nos estaba faltando algo con lo de Gerv... Hablo tan seguido con el por el chat, que no me di cuenta que faltaba esto!!!!! Gracias Gerv por tanto, perdon por tan poco.... Y gracias fedo por darte cuenta.

Comment: Seria bueno agregar enlaces referenciando a g3rv4, como [Tenemos un nuevo moderador: g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3111) ya que los nuevos usuarios(como yo :p) no sabran quien es

Comment: @JuanRivera Gervasio fue moderador, pero solo por un rato ;)

Comment: @gbianchi lo digo porque algunas de las referencias es de cuando fue moderador ;)

Comment: @JuanRivera creo que lo esencial aquí es lo que menciono en la pregunta: que era trabajador de SO y colaboraba en el sitio a nivel personal. Fue designado moderador de forma "tecnocrática" :D Es decir, fue una cosa a nivel técnico (como dijo g3rv4 en la publicación que mencionas: _El objetivo de esto es sólo tener una herramienta más para poder resolver los temitas con las traducciones de forma más eficiente. De ninguna forma mis opiniones deberían ser tomadas con el mismo peso que las de Juan o las de los moderadores elegidos. Yo soy sólo moderador por una razón práctica._)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Honestamente, las cosas que hice por la comunidad sólo fueron inspiradas por la comunidad. Por qué escribimos respuestas? por qué contribuimos traducciones?

Por los puntos? muchos dicen que si... yo creo que es una buena forma de arrancar, pero pertenecer a una comunidad motiva a trabajar por la comunidad.

No tengo dudas de que lo que hice es mucho menos que lo que hacen los usuarios todos los días, sólo que tuve el privilegio de tener acceso al "detrás de bambalinas".

Respecto a traducir.win, antes de irme le transferí el dominio a Stack Overflow. La aplicación sigue hosteada en mi servidor y el código bajo mi usuario de GitHub. En "algún momento", le voy a transferir el proyecto a github.com/StackExchange así queda como open source, SO lo mantiene, y lo hostea en su infraestructura.

No tenemos un estimado de cuándo pasaría esto (me imagino que va a ser cuando yo me canse de hostearlo), pero si me parece genial que SO tome las riendas del proyecto.

Y muchas gracias por hacerme mi post de despedida :D

Comment: que lento que estuve.. te voy a mandar alfajores sin TACC....

Comment: Afortunadamente @fedorqui ha solventado este olvido por nuestra parte en hacerte una publicación de despedida. Aunque, en nuestra defensa, no es una despedida como tal dado que supongo y espero que vas a seguir en el sitio como participante, aunque no ya como empleado. Gracias por tu trabajo durante estos años. Ahora solo te queda una cosa: presentarte a moderador del sitio en las proximas elecciones ;)

Comment: <3 sigo en la vuelta si :)

Comment: ¡Que los éxitos te sigan acompañando estimado :D muchas gracias por tantos aportes a la comunidad!

Comment: Has vuelto :O rebienvenido

Comment: el que se va sin que lo echen... gracias!

Answer (score 10):

Tuve el gran placer de trabajar a lado de g3rv4 por varios años y aunque nuestros departamentos nunca fueron los mismos, siempre pudimos mantener una relación profesional muy bonita entre los dos. Pasamos varios momentos difíciles también mientras la empresa estaba en proceso de crecimiento pero con o sin dificultades, siempre recordaré a g3rv4 como una persona dotada en cuestiones del desarollo de software al igual que su presencia profesional.

Ya han mencionado las contribuciones que se hicieron a la comunidad con respuestas y ayuda general pero también con Traducir.win, lo cual nos permitió traducir el sitio (y los otros sitio internacionales) con más facilidad en un entorno chulo. Pero lo que me gustaría mencionar es que, a pesar de sus techno-habilidades, yo extranare a g3rv4 como persona más que nada. Me quedo con el regalo de haberlo conocido en persona y de haber colaborado con él por various años aquí.

Les dejo [esta entrevista](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_cJCk4X4c) que hicimos en 2017 (para los que no lo han visto).

Comment: Espero que el enlace a esa entrevista no haya sido para presumir camisa de SO en español ante @gbianchi y yo que no tenemos ;)

Comment: :) ha sido un gusto, Juan!